# Change the lua version that redis-server uses

Tags: ubuntu, lua, redis

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 in VirtualBox and I have installed Lua5.3.1:

wheris lua

lua: /usr/bin/lua5.3

Though, if I run a script with:

redis-cli --eval 'scriptname'

redis will use "Lua 5.1" (found with 'print(_VERSION)' in the script).

I need to be running with Lua5.3 because I need support for large integers.
How can I change the version to run on redis? 
Thank you!

Comment: RUN [eval 'return _VERSION' 0 ] in redis-cli to check your version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to configure the version of Lua that the Redis server uses.

There are a few tickets about upgrading the Lua version, but they aren't very promising. A [quote](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2843#issuecomment-154341308) from the creator of Redis:

> we don't have good reasons to upgrade to 5.3 since it breaks existing Lua scripts and for Redis most features of 5.3 are not critical to have...

Some other tickets:

- [Upgrade Lua to 5.2.0](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/253)
- [Update Lua to 5.2](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/1579)